# Por que MOD(11.2,2) dá 1,2 e não 0?

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso pegar o resto de uma divisão no ORACLE e estou utilizando MOD que funciona muito bem com números inteiros porém quando se utiliza numeros decimais dá problema.
Ex : MOD(11,2) = 1 ok
MOD(11.2,2) = 1,2 Errado o certo no meu entendimento seria 0 pois 11,2/2 = 5,6 exato

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda

obrigado

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados? (_Oracle Database, SQL Server, mariaDB etc._)

Comment: Bom dia Amigo

Oracle 10g

Answer (score 1):

O resultado que você esperava `MOD(11.2,2) = 0` está incorreto pois **o resultado da divisão sempre será um número inteiro** já **o resto da divisão pode ou não ser um número inteiro** logo o resultado correto é 1,2 pois divide-se 10 por 2 que resulta no número inteiro 5.

Se fôssemos seguir sua lógica, qualquer número existente resultaria em 0, pois sempre da para dividir por 2 se for aceito como resultado da divisão um número real(tipo dividir 3 mod 2, vai dar 1,5 e o resto = 0 o que está errado).

Comment: Oi amigo, obrigado por responder

Comment: Oi amigo, obrigado por responder
Porém imagina 11.3 / 2 com apenas 1 casa decimal
Daria 5,6 e sobraria 0,01
Esta é a conta que preciso, assim fiz na mão mesmo
O cenário é o seguinte : é uma espécie de rateio entre 2 ou mais beneficiários de um certo valor e estava dando erro 
Por exemplo 238,93 dividido por 2 beneficiarios : R$ 119,46 para o primeiro e o restante deste rateio (R$ 0,01) iria para o segundo R$ 119,47.
Para meu espanto . select mod(238.93,2) from dual; resulta em 0.93